# S3 backend for fault tolerance when using Rocksdb state store in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark streaming application on EKS(Spark version 3.3.1) with RocksDB as state store provider.
Rocksdb is enabled using the config property

```
spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider
```

How do I configure S3 as backend for fault tolerance, so that Rocksdb uses S3 in case the node dies on which the spark streaming application is running?

Tried config property `spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation` set to S3 path. But I don't want our application to write state metadata in S3 all the time because it will be slower and contradict Rocksdb advantage of managing state in the native memory. I just want S3 for fault tolerance in case anything goes wrong with the application node. So can anyone please suggest how do we make this happen?